# Chamar métodos DAO foreach jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Estou iniciando meus estudos em jsp e me deparei com a seguinte situação: quero usar o forEach do jstl **c:foreach** e quero usar uma lista que é retornada pelo meu método DAO.

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="dao" class="teste.ContatoDAO"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Endereco</th>
    </tr>
     <c:forEach var="contato" items="${dao.findAllContatos}">
        <tr>
            <td>${contato.nome}</td>
            <td>${contato.endereco}</td>
            <td>${contato.email}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Onde esse **${dao.findAllContatos}** é o meu método do DAO que retorna uma lista de objetos contato. Porém, o jsp acha que findAllContatos é uma propriedade quando na verdade é um método. Como fazer para contornar esse problema? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Oi amigo, você já tentou tratar como método?
Tipo: `dao.findAllContatos()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Como sugerido pelo Andrew, use dao.findAllContatos().

Expression language só pega métodos getter sem a necessidade de usar parênteses. Nos demais métodos, seu uso se faz necessário.

Procure pela apostila de Java para Web disponibilizada em PDF pela Caelum. Lá, você vai encontrar uma explicação mais detalhada.